# Can't find how to pass a variable from one form to another c#

Tags: c#, sql, string, variables, global-variables

I can't seem to find any resources to specifically help me with my problem. I want to be able to pass my variable that I have retrieved from my table to another form so I can tell who has signed in.

I want to be able to pass the variable called signedin(string) or the variable x(int) to my form called AddStudentAccForm.cs  depending if it is easier to pass an integer or string.

I'd be very grateful for any help anyone could provide! Thank you!

This is my code where I create the variable in my form called StartMenu.cs:

```
private void TeacherLoginButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {



        string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["myconnectionstring"].ConnectionString;
        SqlConnection connect = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
        connect.Open();



        SqlCommand command10 = new SqlCommand(@"SELECT [Username], [Password] FROM TeacherDetails WHERE ([Username]=@username  AND [Password]=@password);", connect);


        command10.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", usernameTlogin.Text);
        command10.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", passwordTlogin.Text);
        SqlDataReader reader;
        reader = command10.ExecuteReader();
        int count = 0;

            while (reader.Read())
            {
                count = count + 1;


            }
            if( count == 1)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Usename and password is correct");

                this.Hide();
                TeacherDashboardForm TeacherDashboard = new TeacherDashboardForm();
                TeacherDashboard.Show();
            }
            else if (count > 1)
            {

                MessageBox.Show("BEEP BOOP ERROR");
            }
            else
            {

                MessageBox.Show("Username or password is incorrect");
            }
            connect.Close();
            connect.Open();
            SqlCommand command11 = new SqlCommand(@"SELECT [TeacherID] FROM TeacherDetails WHERE ( [Username]=@username AND [Password]= @password)", connect);
            command11.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", usernameTlogin.Text);
            command11.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", passwordTlogin.Text);

            reader = command11.ExecuteReader();
            int x = 0;
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    x = reader.GetInt32(0);

                }

                String signedin;
                signedin = x.ToString();

                MessageBox.Show(signedin);
    }
```

Comment: int or string doesn't matter you can send that in the same way however this is a question that has been awnsered quite a lot, I think that if you search for it you will find it.

Comment: Okay thank you, I still can't really find anything to specifically apply to my code

Comment: Create an overloaded constructor in your second form that accepts a parameter of the type you need to pass.  When you initialize your second form, pass in the value that you would like to have access to.  Alternatively, you can pass a class object from one form to another as a parameter allowing all forms who contain a reference to said object to manipulate the properties where needed.

Comment: Also FYI, http://grantwinney.com/passing-data-between-two-forms-in-winforms/

Answer (score 1):

You need to organize your code in classes/models which represent your software architecture.

**Like you have to create class:**

```
    public static class Sql
        {

     public static AuthenticationModel Login(string userName, string password)
            {
                DataTable dt = GetResponseTable("Select UserID,Password from User where userName=" + userName);
                AuthenticationModel details = new AuthenticationModel{LoginStatus = "Failed"};
                if(dt..Rows.Count > 0 )
                  details = new AuthenticationModel{ LoginStatus = "Success", UserName = userName, UserId = dt["UserID"].toString();

                return details;
            }

private static DataTable GetResponseTable(string StoredProcedureName)
        {
            SqlConnection Con = new SqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DefaultConnection"].ConnectionString);

            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            Con.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(StoredProcedureName, Con);
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            da.Fill(dt);
            Con.Close();
            return dt;
        }

    }
```

And use this above model across the application to check for valid user. This is not the only way but you can have many more ways to organize the software model.

Comment: Thank you very much for the help! Yes I am relatively new. Do I have to declare all of these variables in the class as there are a lot of underlined things.

Comment: Things like AuthenticationModel and DataTable

Comment: AuthenticationModel  is another class you need to define where in you will store the response eg. LoginStatus of type string, userid of type string etc. DataTable is part of namespace System.Data. for that you can refer http://www.dotnetperls.com/datatable

Answer (score 0):

AddStudentAccForm.cs
StartMenu.cs

Create an Object for "StartMenu.cs" in "AddStudentAccForm.cs" once you get the status "signedIn" as

```
StartMenu objStart = new StartMenu(signedIn);
```

In StartMenu.cs you can retrive this value in a Parameterized Constructor then you can use it accordingly

```
Class StartMenu
{
    StartMenu(string signedIn)
    {
        //use your value 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For example if you want to pass the value for name from Form1 to Form2 just Add a static field declaration on Form2 to hold the Name value and from Form1 you can access those static field like that Form2.Name

```
public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    public static string Name;
    public static int value;
    public Form2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        label1.Text = Name+ value.ToString();
    }
}
```

and in Form1 if I just want to pass the value just do that.

in my case I will pass on Button event click

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form2.value = 10;
        Form2.Name = "Felicio";
        Form2 form = new Form2();
        form.Show();
    }
```